# Unable to register for events with hyphenated email address

Tags: civievent, contacts, online-registration

Someone tried to register for an event with a hyphenated last name.  Her email address is first.last-hyphenated@domain.com.  CiviCRM says "Please enter a valid email address" and will not allow her to register.

How can I allow hyphens to be passed through Event Registration and mailing list signups?

I am running CiviCRM 5.23.3 with MySQL 8.0.18 and PHP 7.3.14.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Which CMS and is the event configured to allow creating a user account in the CMS?

Comment: Hi Demerit.  Thanks for responding.  I am using WordPress and according to the CiviCRM Profiles, all have No account create option selected under "WordPress user account registration option"

Comment: Ok thanks. It seems to work at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org using https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register/?reset=1&id=3 (it seems to be in German at the moment but I don't think that would matter). So either it's fixed in a later version, you have some extension that's causing it, or there's something about the event config on your site that's different. At wpmaster if you configure an event similar to yours are you able to reproduce the problem there?

Comment: It may not be related to your issue, but please note that CiviCRM doesn't currently support MySQL 8. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-8